Editar/eliminar commit remoto github
Tengo un commit errante en mi repo remoto de github:

El commit muestra claramente una llave que use para pruebas y removí posteriormente:

El commit quedo registrado y ahora me gustaría eliminarlo o editarlo, he notado que github me notificó de esta situación, tengo entendido que si modificas el repo local se modifica el remoto también.

Si modificas el local y haces un force push, "desaparece" del remoto. Pero sinceramente, si ya se ha subido lo que debes hacer es invalidar esa clave y generar una nueva.

Si puedes regenerar el token no hay problema en que lo dejes así.

Intente la solución de @ffflabs en un repo de prueba y funciona por eso es que le di un voto, pero el repo original es muy largo, Termine utilizando filter-repo para eliminar todo el archivo del repo, luego se creo un nuevo branch con el manifest sin token, se rebaso y se empujo al remoto, todo el día en esto, vaya error, saludos

ojo si hay más colaboradores en el proyecto, tienen que ponerse todos de acuerdo para hacer un procedimiento como este. Es más, puede que simplemente sea mala idea tratar de borrar este commit de la historia.

Si estamos hablando de un repo público, y tu token estuvo expuesto, entonces sí o sí debes invalidarlo y crear uno nuevo, y seguir las mejores prácticas como almacenarlo en variables de entorno.
Ahora, para eliminar ese commit, que mal que mal sigue existiendo, lo que debieras hacer es un rebase. Primero, te traes ese commit a tu local con un git pull.
Ahora supongamos que este commit es el 6fc987362c.  Vamos a hacer un rebase en donde se omitirá este commit y te reescribirán todos los commits siguientes:
 git rebase 6fc987362c^

Vas a ver en tu consola algo como
    pick 6fc98736 publica el token que debió haber sido privado
    pick 970c9ccf hace otros cambios que queremos preservar
    pick e76dea34 regenera assets
    pick 8828a542 pasa 463 tests
    pick e61d35b2 implementa interfaces

La primera línea contiene el commit que quieres eliminar. Si quitas esa línea y guardas en el editor, se aplicarán todos los commits que siguen (y su SHA cambiará) mientras que el commit que querías borrar habrá desaparecido de la historia del proyecto.
Hecho lo anterior sólo debes hacer git push -f para pisar el remoto con la nueva historia.
